# our Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli

Error while creating a React Native project. I've done all the updates. and my Ruby -V is also 3.1.2 but error still same How can I solve the problem?.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution is to upgrade your ruby version to 2.7.5

I also face the same issue when I try to install react-native on my MacBook and I solve it by upgrading my ruby version to 2.7.5 and installing Cocoapods. The link below will guide you on how to upgrade ruby on MacBook https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b